# Is it possible to import classes specified by string in typescript?

Tags: typescript

So I have

```
import { AccountData } from '../settings/AccountData/AccountData';
import { AccountDelete } from '../settings/AccountDelete/AccountDelete';
import { AccountLogin } from '../settings/AccountLogin/AccountLogin';
import { AccountPassword } from '../settings/AccountPassword/AccountPassword';
import { AddTrack } from '../settings/AddTrack/AddTrack';

import { EditUser } from '../settings/EditUser/EditUser';
import { MakePlaylist } from '../settings/MakePlaylist/MakePlaylist';
import { MakeWishlist } from '../settings/MakeWishlist/MakeWishlist';
import { ManageAdmins } from '../settings/ManageAdmins/ManageAdmins';
import { ManageEditors } from '../settings/ManageEditors/ManageEditors';
import { ManageRadiostation } from '../settings/ManageRadiostation/ManageRadiostation';
import { ManageTracks } from '../settings/ManageTracks/ManageTracks';
import { ManageUsers } from '../settings/ManageUsers/ManageUsers';
```

and later I have

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', redirectTo: ['AccountData']},
    { path: 'AccountData', name: 'AccountData', component: AccountData },
    { path: 'AccountDelete', name: 'AccountDelete', component: AccountDelete },
    { path: 'AccountLogin', name: 'AccountLogin', component: AccountLogin },
    { path: 'AccountPassword', name: 'AccountPassword', component: AccountPassword },
    { path: 'AddTrack', name: 'AddTrack', component: AddTrack },

    { path: 'EditUser', name: 'EditUser', component: EditUser },
    { path: 'MakePlaylist', name: 'MakePlaylist', component: MakePlaylist },
    { path: 'MakeWishlist', name: 'MakeWishlist', component: MakeWishlist },
    { path: 'ManageAdmins', name: 'ManageAdmins', component: ManageAdmins },
    { path: 'ManageEditors', name: 'ManageEditors', component: ManageEditors },
    { path: 'ManageRadiostation', name: 'ManageRadiostation', component: ManageRadiostation },
    { path: 'ManageTracks', name: 'ManageTracks', component: ManageTracks },
    { path: 'ManageUsers', name: 'ManageUsers', component: ManageUsers }
])
class A ...
```

I also have to change this now and then when adding some stuff.
Would it be possible to somehow create and array of the components like

```
var components = ['AccountData', ...]
var routes = components.map((comp) => { import comp from '../settings/' + comp + '/' + comp; return new Route(comp, comp, comp); }

@RouteConfig(routes)
class A ....
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible I am afraid. It would be possible to do it in a way that would make it work in the transpiled javascript. But it is not possible to get it to work with the typescript compiler.

Comment: Would this be considered bad practice?

Comment: Well it just would not work in any usable way. No code completion etc.

Comment: Since this would have to be implemented as syntactic sugar, doesn't it really depend just on whether the analyzer recognizes this as declaration? I mean, if you want this in code completion you could just tell the IDE to include it...